# after submit the views functions do nothing

Tags: html, django

hello this my html formulaire

```html
<div id="Admin" class="tabcontent">
  <form  method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h2> Vous ètes un Admin ?</h2>

    <div class="container" action >
      <input type="hidden"  name="user_type" value="1">
      <label for ="id_email"><b>Votre Email</b></label>
      <input id="id_email" type="text" placeholder="Entrer Votre Email" name="email" required>

      <label for ="id_password" ><b>Mot de Passe</b></label>
      <input id="id_password" type="password" placeholder="Entrer Votre Mot de passe" name="password" required>
      <button type="submit" >Login</button>
      <label>
         <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> souviens de moi
      </label>
    </div>
```

and this the views function called login

```
def login(request):

    context = {}

    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, "login.html")

    if request.POST:
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data.POST['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)

            if user:
                login(request, user)
                if user.user_type == '1':
                    return render(request, "administrateur.html")
                elif user.user_type == '2':
                    return render(request, "entrepreneur.html")


        else:
            print("errors")
            form = AuthenticationForm()

    context['login_form'] = form

    return render(request, "entrepreneur", context)
```

and i create in form files this class

```
class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.PasswordInput()
```

this my 3 user class in model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type=((1,"admin"),(2,"entrepreneur"))
    user_type=models.IntegerField(default=1,choices=user_type)
    email=models.EmailField(unique=True,blank=True)
    objects = UserManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
#admin-----------------------------------------------------------------------
class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    date_naissance = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name

# Entrepreneur----------------------------------------------------------------
class Entrepreneur(models.Model):
    user=  models.OneToOneField(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    date_naissance=models.DateField()
    adresse_entr=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    telephone=models.IntegerField()
    occupation=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    annnee_exp=models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name
```

when i submit it stay in the login.html and dont redirect to any other html's page

i did not find where is my problem
maybe i have a problem on passing data from htm to views??
maybe in my models class???
or in form or views
what is my errors!!!!!????? plesae help me

thank you

Comment: Is your data being saved in db? If so than you have to redirect the user to particular URL not render them.

Answer (score 0):

try to put this

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
```

Also I am not sure if you have properly closed your form with a <\form>.
Please check it.